# Error for Python 3.4.1 regarding string pattern and bytes-like object

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, byte

I'm new to Python and stack overflow.

I'm trying to follow a tutorial on youtube (outdated I'm guessing based on the error I get) regarding fetching stock prices.

Here is the following program:

```
import urllib.request
import re


html = urllib.request.urlopen('http://finance.yahoo.com/q?uhb=uh3_finance_vert_gs_ctrl2&fr=&type=2button&s=AAPL')

htmltext = html.read()

regex = '<span id="yfs_l84_aapl">.+?</span>'

pattern = re.compile(regex)

price = re.findall(pattern, htmltext)

print(price)
```

Since this is Python 3, I had to research on urllib.request and use those methods instead of a simple urllib.urlopen.

Anyways, when I run it, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Harshil/Desktop/stockFetch.py", line 13, in <module>
    price = re.findall(pattern, htmltext)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/re.py", line 206, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

I realize the error and attempted to fix it by adding the following:

```
  codec = html.info().get_param('charset', 'utf8')
htmltext = html.decode(codec)
```

But it gives me another error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Harshil/Desktop/stockFetch.py", line 9, in <module>
    htmltext = html.decode(codec)
AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Hence, after spending reasonable amount of time, I don't know what to do. All I want to do is get the price for AAPL so I can further continue to build a general program to fetch prices for an array of stocks and use the prices in future programs.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are barking up the right tree. Try decoding the actual HTML byte string rather than the urlopen HTTPResponse:

```
htmltext = html.read()
codec = html.info().get_param('charset', 'utf8')
htmltext = htmltext.decode(codec)
price = re.findall(pattern, htmltext)
```

Comment: If the page is known to be 'utf-8' encoded, `htmltext = htmlbytes.decode(encoding='utf-8').  Or, if your pattern is limited to ascii, prefix it with 'b'.

Comment: It works! I see what I did wrong. Thanks a ton!

The only problem is my result outputs the whole sentence '<span ... </span>' so I should be able to fix that but thanks again!